# JFace TreeViewer first column

Tags: eclipse, jface, treeviewer

[image]I have a jface treeviewer with 2 columns. When I hover my mouse over any element in the first column, I see the mouse pointer turning to that of the one we see when we hover an url or a web page link ( I mean a hand pointer ). and also the color of that particular cell turns white irrespective of what background color it had. And for the other columns I see no such effects. Only in the first column, I see this. How do I disable this 'effect' for first column? Thanks. Please see the below pic. you can see the highlighted thing in the first column.

Comment: It would probably help to show the relevant code and a screen shot of what you're describing.

Comment: Riz, thanks. I attached a screenshot, would that help? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the highlighting is due to default single cell selection by the framework on treeviewer. Set SWT.FULL_SELECTION to have full row selection that solves white background as well.